# Excel operation in Tosca

Tags: tosca

How to find second occurrence in excel file using Tosca. For eg. if you have list of names and few names are repeated, find the second occurrence of that particular name.

I tried to get the count and store it in buffer.

Comment: define "second occurence". If there is "David" in A1, A2 and B1, which is the second? If there is "Tom" in A2, B4 and C1, which is the second?

Comment: A2 and B4 are second occurrence

Comment: how do you know it?